# Devise allow email uniqueness within scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm in the process of upgrading a large project from rails 2 to rails 3, as a part of that upgrade I'm replacing a very old restful_athentication with devise.

The problem I'm having is that in the existing users table emails are validated like this.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :account_id # No dupes within account
```

So if I add the index from the migration to add devise to users it WILL fail.

Is there a way that I can use

```
add_index :users, [:email,:account_id]
```

And have devise work properly?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working on my own, I added the following to config/initializer/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email , :account_id]
```